# Possible to collect YUM/RPM history centrally?

Tags: linux, monitoring, yum, package-management

I have some CentOS 5.x servers which auto-update nightly via yum.

Root mailboxes from these hosts are forwarded to a central address, so if new updates are installed I can see that in the e-mails. This is not a very flexible solution...

Is there an open-source solution to follow either YUM updates or RPM installations centrally? Like a database that would collect the update history and make it available via a single web service.

RHEL & up2date provides an on-line solution for this IIRC, but is there anything for the free RHEL derived distros?

Comment: nightly? wow - that's mighty frequent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [Spacewalk](https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/).

Comment: cheers, I knew there was something out there.

Comment: Do note that Spacewalk does require an RHN agent rather than using simple `yum`, and these agents can be somewhat hefty to deploy in a larger CentOS environment.

Answer (score 2):

[Pulp](http://pulpproject.org/) is the latest solution from Redhat for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can read YUM's log file with syslog-ng and then send it to a central log server.